# Backup and Restoration of Running Schema In Another Database That Already Have Other Schemas

Tags: oracle10g, backup

I have a running database with only one dba (i.e. other than sys, system) "abc". Under this oracle user I have tables, views, sequences, procedures, functions etc. Now I have to copy both the data and schema to another database at another machine that already have a dozen schemas running (one under each separate dba). I have following concerns:

(1) I have to rename the schema at old machine, from "abc" to "pqr" before moving to the new machine.

(2) Inside my procedures and functions, I am using AUTHID CURRENT_USER, therefore have to use "abc." qualifier before name of tables, views, sequences, procedures, functions. When changing schema name, is there some automatic way to change qualifiers too.

(3) In order to copy data, I know only one way, which is to take backup of database of only one user "abc" (i.e. not take backup of sys, system). Then restore that to the new database. Can this in anyway destroy the other schemas or their data.

(4) In my schema, I am creating oracle users with limited rights using a procedure. The new usernames are stored in a Users table. I am also creating database roles and associating users with roles. The rolenames are stored in a Roles table. When migrating to new machine I have to make sure to prefix my users and roles with something unique so I not disturb oracle users created by other schemas.

(5) I know that in the new database, there have to be a new dba user called "pqr". Do I also have to have sysdba privilege. I am not responsible about the whole database at new machine, I am responsible about my schema only. Being a sysdba, can I in anyway hurt other dbas (like dropping them, or changing their schemas). If I not have sysdba privilege, what limitations do I get. I am using OracleText so have to use some built-in packages. I also have to create physical directory on file system in windows. I also have to create, alter (change password), drop roles and users via stored procedures when connected to database using "pqr".

Both old and new database are running on separate dedicated machines. Its windows server 2003 with oracle 10gr1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option would be to use the [Oracle export utility](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10825/dp_export.htm#i1007466) (classic or DataPump) to take a logical backup of the `abc` schema in the first database and to import the backup using the [Oracle import utility](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10825/dp_import.htm#i1007653) into the new database.  If you're using the classic version, you'd use the `FROMUSER` and `TOUSER` parameters to specify that you want to import the data into a different schema.  If you're using the DataPump version, you'd use the `REMAP_SCHEMA` parameter.  The DataPump version will be more efficient if you have a relatively large amount of data.

Unfortunately, though, there is no way to change explicit schema qualifiers.  You'll need to edit the code after you import it or pull the code from your source control system, edit the code, and deploy it to the new database.

Comment: Thanks Justin. Do logical backup includes data? Do pqr have to be sysdba?

Comment: @Atif - Yes, an export includes data by default (you can specify that you don't want data).  Neither schema needs to have the `DBA` role.

Comment: Where to run expdb command? Its not running in command prompt or sqlplus.

Comment: @Atif - It is a command line utility (it can also be invoked from something like Enterprise Manager).  Are you looking at the examples in the documentation I linked to?  What command are you executing and what error(s) are you getting?

Comment: sorry, typing mistake, it has to be expdp, not expdb.